# Connecting logic gates with transistors

Tags: electrical-engineering

I've been trying to create different parts of a basic 4 bit computer with transistors like a 4 bit adder, 16 bytes of memory, and registers but when I tried to make a 4 bit counter I failed to find a way to make it out of transistors. I thought a master slave jk flip flop would be a simple way to attempt to build one but after throwing it together and testing each logic gate seperatly, it didn't work.

Comment: Question contains too few details to debug a circuit. Please show us the circuit diagram of the MS JK FF you have made from transistors. Please also tell us the part number or value of all components used in the circuit including the transistors. If I understood the question, you have succeeded in making a single logic gate work, but not succeeded in making a single JK flip flop work. Take a look at this concept of [logic level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_level), [2](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/415837/238590).

Comment: The question is probably more suited to https://electronics.stackexchange.com but don't ask there without the schematic!